# How to change the internal state of a Clock instance in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, testing, clock

I have a service that verifies expiration of dates:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExpirationVerificationService {
  private final Clock clock;

  public boolean hasPassed(Instant instant) {
    return Instant.now(clock).isAfter(instant);
  }
}
```

I want to verify that `hasPassed` returns different values as time passes:

```
public class ExpirationVerificationServiceTest {

  private ExpirationVerificationService service;
  private Clock clock;

  @BeforeEach
  public void init() {
    clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.EPOCH, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    service = new ExpirationVerificationService(clock);
  }

  @Test
  public void testHasExpired() {
    Instant instant = Instant.now(clock).plus(Duration.ofDays(30);
    assertFalse(service.hasPassed(instant));

    // TODO move clock to future
    assertTrue(service.hasPassed(instant));
  }

}
```

How can I update the internal state of the `Clock` instance to be in the future?

note: the actual business logic I'm testing is much more complicated than this example (verifying expiration of Oauth tokens coming from a DB), I can't just use a different `Instant` instance in the past.

Comment: Just set a new `Clock` instance?

Answer (score 2):

`Clock` is effectively just a provider of an `Instant`. You can trivially declare a fixed clock like:

```
Instant fixedInstant = Instant.EPOCH;
Clock clock = () -> fixedInstant;
```

As such, if you want a settable `Clock`, you could declare:

```
AtomicReference<Instant> theInstant = new AtomicReference<>(Instant.EPOCH);
Clock clock = () -> theInstant.get();
```

and then update `theInstant`.